# python - Level-Order Traversal output in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, traversal

Queue Classes to implement A level-order traversal of a binary tree

```
class QNode:
  def __init__ (self, x, p=None):
    self.data = x
    self.next = p
class Queue:
  def __init__ (self):
    self.front = None
    self.back = None

  def isEmpty(self):
    return self.front == None

  def enqueue (self, x):
    p = QNode (x)
    if self.isEmpty( ):
        self.front = p
    else:
        self.back.next = p
    self.back = p

  def dequeue (self):
    if self.isEmpty( ):
        raise KeyError ("Queue is empty.")
    x = self.front.data
    self.front = self.front.next
    if self.front == None:
        self.back == None
    return x
```

The actual Binary Tree Node Class

```
class BSTNode:
  def __init__ (self, x, L=None, R=None):
    self.data = x
    self.left = L
    self.right = R
```

The level-order traversal that I want to make multidimensional

```
  def levelOrder(self):
    ret = []
    Q = Queue()
    if self!=None:
        Q.enqueue(self)
    while not Q.isEmpty():
        p = Q.dequeue()
        ret.append(p.data)
        if p.left!=None:
            Q.enqueue(p.left)
        if p.right!=None:
            Q.enqueue(p.right)
    return ret
```

In the BSTNode class I attempt to do a level-order traversal of the Binary Tree. However, it returns a flat list. How would implement a level-order traversal with a multidimensional array output?

Comment: `levelOrder` appends every node it encounters to the same list, `ret`, so of course you're only going to get one list out of it.  If you want to return a list-of-lists, you have to _create_ those lists: one for each row of the tree, and one more to contain them all.

Comment: Right. I was asking how to create those lists, and maintain the queue implementation that I used for the traversal. Obviously a flat list is not a multidimensional list, the question is rather how can I generate a multidimensional list with the current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. You basically need to queue a delimiter. I made this a "[" for obvious reasons. I queued a "[" when I first enqueued the first node. Then when you go to dequeue, if it is a delimiter that you are dequeueing add another, before adding children, and also append a list with a list of all the values dequeued since the last delimiter. This creates a multidimensional list of your level order traversal. The solution looks as follows

```
def levelOrder(self):
    order = []
    suborder = []
    Q = Queue()
    if self!=None:
        Q.enqueue(BSTNode('['))
        Q.enqueue(self)
    while not Q.isEmpty():
        p = Q.dequeue()
        if p.data is not '[' and p.data is not ']':
            suborder.append(p.data)
        if p.data == '[' and Q.front != None:
            Q.enqueue(BSTNode(']'))
            Q.enqueue(BSTNode('['))
        if p.data == ']':
            order.append(suborder)
            suborder = []
        if p.left!=None:
            Q.enqueue(p.left)
        if p.right!=None:
            Q.enqueue(p.right)
    return order
```